# How do change my column into a time format?

Tags: r, datetime, type-conversion

I've uploaded my table into R posit and to avoid errors showing I uploaded a TIME column but its stored as a character column.

The table is as follows:
ID (identifier of an individual)   //   Time (Date and time of value)   //   Value (Heart Rate Number)

This is the format of the column
[refer to middle column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPjxo.png)

I would like to change this column into its proper format of TIME, but I am not sure how to change it as there is "AM" listed at the end

My objective of analysis for this column is to look at the values throughout the day. (Would putting the time into a different column also help with this?)

I have tried to look up ways to change it with code such as POSIT but I am not sure how to do this with the AM at the end. (e.g. format="%m/%d/%Y **%I**:%M:%S (additionally, what does %I %M and %S refer to in this formatting?))

This is my first time uploading to R so any additional information you can explain would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want datetimes, not times? In that case, you can do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(Id = c(2022484408L, 2022484408L, 2022484408L, 
2022484408L, 2022484408L, 2022484408L, 2022484408L, 2022484408L
), Time = c("4/12/2016 7:21:00 AM", "4/12/2016 7:21:05 AM", "4/12/2016 7:21:10 AM", 
"4/12/2016 7:21:20 AM", "4/12/2016 7:21:25 AM", "4/12/2016 7:22:05 AM", 
"4/12/2016 7:22:10 AM", "4/12/2016 7:22:15 AM"), Value = c(97L, 
102L, 105L, 103L, 101L, 95L, 91L, 93L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))

mutate(df, Time = as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"))

# Output:
          Id Time                Value
       <int> <dttm>              <int>
1 2022484408 2016-12-04 07:21:00    97
2 2022484408 2016-12-04 07:21:05   102
3 2022484408 2016-12-04 07:21:10   105
4 2022484408 2016-12-04 07:21:20   103
5 2022484408 2016-12-04 07:21:25   101
6 2022484408 2016-12-04 07:22:05    95
7 2022484408 2016-12-04 07:22:10    91
8 2022484408 2016-12-04 07:22:15    93
```

In the format argument (`"%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"`):

- %d is day of the month as decimal number (01–31).
- %m is month as decimal number (01–12).
- %Y is year with century
- %I is hours as decimal number (01–12).
- %M is minutes as decimal number (00–59)
- %S is seconds as an integer (00–61), allowing for up to two leap-seconds - %p is AM/PM indicator in the locale.

Note that your data could be month/day/year, or day/year/month - it's unclear if it's April 12th or December 4th. If I guessed wrong, just swap around the %d and %m in the format argument.

For more information on formatting arguments, read the [documentation for strptime](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime), which is what the documentation of `as.POSIXct` refers to.